# How do we capture crash reports from AppStore builds?

Tags: hockeyapp

We have been using HockeyApp for Alpha and Beta distribution and crash reporting. We are planning to submit the app to AppStore. We have created a new slot on HockeyApp with same bundle id as the AppStore build. And included the app ids and keys of the slot in the AppStore build.

Question is, do we have to upload the ipa that we submit to itunnesconnect to the HockeyApp slot as well for crash reporting or crash reports will be captured even if no ipa exits in the HockeyApp Slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For crash reports, it is generally not necessary to upload the `.ipa` file. To get proper crash reports, the only thing you need to upload are the `dSYM` files of the exact same build that will be shipped to your customers through the store.

These `dSYM` files are used to "translate" the gibberish memory address from the raw crash report back to readable method names, file names, and line numbers in a process called "symbolication".
Please be especially aware of the difficulty that enabling Bitcode adds around symbolication: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems#bitcode